# Is there a library in F# that is similar to scalaz, cats and arrow (Kotlin)?

Tags: functional-programming, f#, scalaz, scala-cats, arrow-kt

What is a recommended approach in F# to use "high level" functional patterns? For Scala there are [scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) and [cats](https://github.com/typelevel/cats), even there is [Arrow](https://github.com/arrow-kt/arrow) for Kotlin, though I have not found anything similar for F#.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [FSharpPlus](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpPlus/) library is probably the closest.